# Fabic: Issue connection refused 7050

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create a network from the hyperledger fabic tutorial. I get the following error:

Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:7050: connect: connection refused"

I opened up the port on the Centos 7 Virtual machine and still no luck. The docker container is exposing the port to the host.

I removed all docker containers, images and volumes. I even rebuilt the VM from scratch.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This situation is happened because you called a gRPC to orderer server but your call failed to hit the server. This situation may happen for many reasons, but for most of the cases the situation is happened due to server down(orderer server exit or down due to misconfiguration) or your call failed to hit the server due to misconfiguration.

Comment: Thank You Ok, for ypur explanation. Ok, I guess I'm confused on how the host machine is supposed to be configured to support Hyperledger Fabric. 

The three docker containers do not stay up after running:
./network up
The server just exits, which after looking at the docker container configuration i don't see anything that should stop it from running.

Comment: Not sure how a misconfiguration host machine would be the issue, if all the prerequisites are met

Comment: You can check the logs in docker container with the following command "docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER" which will help you to find the problem.

Comment: Also map the the volumes in docker-compose.yml file properly.

Comment: So checking out the docker logs. I get the following error:
2020-06-30 02:38:44.494 UTC [orderer.common.server] loadLocalMSP -> PANI 004 Failed to get local msp config: could not initialize BCCSP Factories: Failed initializing BCCSP: Could not initialize BCCSP SW [Failed to initialize software key store: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/keystore: permission denied]

Comment: panic: Failed to get local msp config: could not initialize BCCSP Factories: Failed initializing BCCSP: Could not initialize BCCSP SW [Failed to initialize software key store: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/keystore: permission denied]

Comment: I am running as an adminstrator that has full rights to the system.

Comment: It seems OS permission denied problems specially in orderer volums, like
"- ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp" 
It seems the problem is something like "Can't access local volume data, its give permission denied".  Please check the permission status of the local folder where you store crypto material and other related permission.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow encounter this problem before and the port was opened. Somehow it was a mistake where I forgot to put '-a' in command (launch cerificate authorities). Hope it help.

You might also refer this : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html